# How can WriteAttributeString in WriteElementString

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

i need to Write Attribute String in Write Element String if Write Element String contains string values i'am trying this code but it doesn't work

```
        w.WriteStartElement("W-TIBCPTRs");
        w.WriteElementString("TYPTRT", TYPTRT);
            if (Regex.IsMatch(CLAFCNO, @"^\d+$"))
            {
                w.WriteElementString("CLAFCNO", CLAFCNO);
            }
            else
            {
                w.WriteElementString("CLAFCNO", CLAFCNO);
                w.WriteAttributeString("verifier", "Non");
            }
        w.WriteElementString("NUMCLI", NUMCLI);
        w.WriteElementString("TYPACT", TYPACT);
        w.WriteEndElement();
```

if i have a string value in CLAFCNO this is the result do i need

```
<W-TIBCPTR>
  <W-TIBCPTRs>
    <TYPTRT>FDR2 R</TYPTRT>
    <CLAFCNO verifier="NO">5D1</CLAFCNO>
    <NUMCLI>0067781</NUMCLI>
    <TYPACT>D</TYPACT>
  </W-TIBCPTRs>
</W-TIBCPTR>
```

if i have a number i need this result

```
<W-TIBCPTR>
  <W-TIBCPTRs>
    <TYPTRT>FDR2 R</TYPTRT>
    <CLAFCNO>5D1</CLAFCNO>
    <NUMCLI>0067781</NUMCLI>
    <TYPACT>D</TYPACT>

  </W-TIBCPTRs>
</W-TIBCPTR>
```

Comment: What is the XML you're trying to produce?

Comment: if i have a string value in CLAFCNO this is the result do i need <W-TIBCPTR>
  <W-TIBCPTRs>
    <TYPTRT>FDR2 R</TYPTRT>
    <CLAFCNO verifier="NO">5D1</CLAFCNO>
    <NUMCLI>0067781</NUMCLI>
    <TYPACT>D</TYPACT>
   
  </W-TIBCPTRs>
</W-TIBCPTR>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for [WriteString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
w.WriteStartElement("CLAFCNO");
w.WriteAttributeString("verifier", "Non");
w.WriteString(CLAFCNO);
w.WriteEndElement();
```